# incollection: correct information for parts and chapters

Tags: biblatex

In the "Handbook of mechanical engineering" there are 3 parts consisting of chapters and then sections (authors belong to the sections). I used `incollection` (`biblatex`) as entrytype to cite a certain section. What would be the best way to add the information of the part and chapter (here: *Part B: Applications in Mechanical Engineering*, *Chapter 7: Manufacturing Engineering*) the section belongs to?

Here is the example:

```
@incollection{Tekkaya2009,
    Author = {Tekkaya, A. E.},
    Booktitle = {Handbook of Mechanical Engineering},
    Chapter = {7.2},
    Editor = {Grote, K.-H. and Antonsson, E. K.},
    Pages = {554-606},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Metal Forming},
    Year = {2009}}
```

Comment: Is there an author credited with the whole Handbook, or is it an editor? What exactly are you likely to cite: just chapters, sometimes parts or the whole Handbook? Better yet, could you please give us a minimal working example (MWE), with a bib file containing two chapters, and the Handbooks own entry?

Comment: The only thing I struggle with is where to put the aforementioned information on part and chapter correctly in terms of bibliographic correctness.

Comment: Have you tried the `@mvbook` or `@mvcollection` data types proposed by `biblatex` (see the latest manual version)? Without more information on your part, and what is exactly your expected result, it's hard to give more precise help.